# Evaluating a line integral

Tags: calculus, integration

What's the quickest way of evaluating

$$ \int_{|y| = r} \frac{1}{|x - y|^2} d \sigma_y $$ in real plane, where $x \in B(0,r)$.
Could complex contour integration help us here?

Comment: In case if you are interested,the identity $\frac{1}{\alpha^2+\beta^2-2\alpha\beta\cos(x)}=\frac{2}{\alpha^2-\beta^2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(\beta/\alpha)^n\cos(nx)+\frac{1}{\alpha^2-\beta^2}$ would be a good starting point for a solution without contour integration

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume $d\sigma_y$ is an element of arc length.  Then if $y=r \, (\cos{t},\sin{t})$, then $d\sigma_y = r \,dt$.  If we also let $x=\rho (\cos{p},\sin{p})$, $\rho \lt r$ the integral becomes

$$\begin{align}I &= r \int_0^{2 \pi} \frac{dt}{(r \cos{t} - \rho \cos{p})^2 + (r \sin{t} - \rho \sin{p})^2}\\ &= r \int_0^{2 \pi} \frac{dt}{r^2+\rho^2-2 r \rho \cos{(t-p)}} \\ &= r \int_0^{2 \pi} \frac{dt}{r^2+\rho^2-2 r \rho \cos{t}} \end{align}$$

Now complex contour integration may help us here.  Let $z=e^{i t}$, $dt = -i dz/z$, and the integral becomes

$$i r \oint_{|z|=1} \frac{dz}{r \rho z^2 - (r^2+\rho^2) z + r \rho} $$

The integrand has poles at

$$z_{\pm} = \frac{r^2+\rho^2\pm (r^2-\rho^2)}{2 r \rho} = \begin{cases}r/\rho & +\\\rho/r & - \end{cases}$$

Because $\rho \lt r$, we are only concerned with $z_-$.  The integral is then $i 2 \pi$ times the residue at the pole $z=z_-$, which is

$$I = i 2 \pi \frac{i r}{2 r \rho (\rho/r) - r^2-\rho^2}= \frac{2 \pi r}{r^2-\rho^2} $$

Comment: awesome as always!